# ¿Como puedo hacer compatible un String^ con un std::string?

Tags: c++, windows-forms

Tengo un código que realice en visual Studio con un windows form. tengo un boton que se llama archivo, este realiza la apertura del explorador de archivos y almacena la ruta de un txt seleccionado. Para ello se declara la variable:
private: System::String^ filePath;
Este es el código del botón:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    //Este codigo implementa la apertura del archivo y genera su ruta alm,acenada en fileName
    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "Archivos de texto (*.txt)|*.txt|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->Title = "Seleccionar archivo de texto";
    // Mostrar el diálogo y comprobar si el usuario seleccionó un archivo
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
        // Obtener la ruta del archivo seleccionado
        filePath = openFileDialog1->FileName;
    }
    if (filePath != nullptr) {
        tablaDeBatch batch{filePath};
    }
    else {
        MessageBox::Show("No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
    }
    
}
```

tablaDeBatch es un constructor que recibe un std::string

```
tablaDeBatch::tablaDeBatch(std::string arch) {
this->arch = arch;
string linea;
ifstream f(arch);
...}
```

Para solucionarlo trate de usar la biblioteca marshal con la siguiente línea de código:

```
std::string nativeFilePath = marshal_as<std::string>(filePath);
tablaDeBatch batch{nativeFilePath};
```

Pero me marca muchos errores, alguna solución?

Comment: Qué errores obtienes?

Comment: no se permite un puntero común a una clase interface o ref de C++/CLI y
"IServiceProvider" ambiguo

Answer (score 1):

Según [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405251/13419694) puedes usar [varias funciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) para convertir de uno a otro.

Para convertir de `System::String^` a `std::string` puedes hacerlo así:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

System::String^ managed = "test";
std::string unmanaged = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managed)
```

El ejemplo es el mismo de la publicación mencionada.